# slurm does not provide valid information via email?

Tags: hpc, slurm

I use

```
#SBATCH --mail-type=end
#SBATCH --mail-user=myemail@gmail.com
```

in my `script.sh` to send me valid information about the job. But what I received is empty without any valid information:

```
JOB NAME:
EXIT STATUS: COMPLETED

SUMBITTED ON:
STARTED ON:
ENDED ON:

PARTITION:
USED NODES:
ALLOCATED RESOURCES:

JOB AVERAGE CPU FREQUENCY:
JOB AVERAGE USED RAM:

JOB STDOUT TO `'
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information sent by Slurm is really site-dependent as it relies on a script written by the system administrators and referred to by the `MailProg` configuration parameter. You can find it with `scontrol show config | grep MailProg`. Reasons for which it might not work could be multiple, depending on wether that script fetches information from the controller (with `scontrol`) or from the accounting database (`with sacct`), or (as it appears to be from the template) from both. So your best option is to ask the question to your cluster administrators.